# JavaScript Form Validation on submit

Tags: javascript

I have a simple form and am validating onchange and need a final validation onsubmit. I am displaying a message to the right of the inputbox on error. I'm trying to keep this at DOM 1 compatible.

**HTML**

```
<form id = "myForm" action = "" onsubmit = "return validateForm(this);">
                <table class = "table-submit" border = "0">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Username: 
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type = "text" id = "username" 
                                size = "30" maxlength = "30"
                                onchange = "validateUsername(this, 'msgUsername')" />
                        </td>
                        <td id = "msgUsername">
                            &nbsp;
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Password: 
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type = "password" id = "password" 
                                size = "30" maxlength = "30"
                                onchange = "validatePassword(this, 'msgPassword')" />
                        </td>
                        <td id = "msgPassword">
                            &nbsp;
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>
                        &nbsp;
                        <input type = "submit" value = "Submit"  />
                        &nbsp;
                        <input type = "reset" value = "Clear" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function validateUsername(myItem, myElement) {
var dom = document.getElementById(myElement);

    if (myItem.value.length < 3) {
        dom.innerHTML = " Username needs to be a minimum of 3 characters! ";
        return false;
    }
    else {
        dom.innerHTML = "";
        return true;
    }
}

function validatePassword(myItem, myElement) {
var dom = document.getElementById(myElement);

    if (myItem.value.length < 5) {
        dom.innerHTML = " Password needs to be a minimum of 5 characters! ";
        return false;
    }
    else {
        dom.innerHTML = "";
        return true;
    }
}

function validateForm (itm) {

    // kind of stuck here...
}
```

As you may of noticed, I am a bit stuck on my validateForm() function. 
The code validates on each inputbox onchange event.
Not sure what is the best way to go from here. I thought about doing an If for my both single input box validation, but I would need to send each parameters which is what i was trying to avoid by using this. 
Would like some suggestions.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/W4g4e/7/

Answer (score 0):

Separate concerns. Instead of having the validate functions not only validate but also report your painting your self into a corner. Instead have a validate function which only returns true/false and another that is your onChange event handler which calls the validate function and displays the error message if needed. Then your onSubmit handler can easily call the validation functions in an if/else block to allow or cancel the submit action.

```
function validateUsername(username) {
  return username.length >= 3;
}

function validatePassword(password) {
  return password.length >= 5;
}

function showErrorFn(divId, message) {
  var div = document.getElementById(divId);
  message = " " + message;
  return function(message) {
    div.innerHTML = message;
  };
}

function makeChangeHandler(myItem, validationFn, errorFn) {
  return function(e) {
    if (validationFn(myItem.value)) {
      return true;
    } else {
      errorFn();
      return false;
    }
  };
}

function makeSubmitHandler(usernameEl, passwordEl) {
  return function(e) {
    if (validateUsername(usernameEl.value) && validatePassword(passwordEl.value)) {
      return true;
    } else {
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
}

var usernameEl = document.getElementById("username");
var usernameErrorEl = document.getElementById("msgUsername");
usernameEl.addEventListener("change", makeChangeHandler(
  usernameEl,
  validateUsername,
  showErrorFn("Username must be more then 3 characters")
);

var usernameEl = document.getElementById("password");
var usernameErrorEl = document.getElementById("msgPassword");
usernameEl.addEventListener("change", makeChangeHandler(
  usernameEl,
  validatePassword,
  showErrorFn("Password must be more then 5 characters")
);

var formEl = document.getElementById("myForm");
formEl.addEventListener("submit", makeSubmitHandler(usernameEl, password));
```

Comment: That's great, but I am trying to keep it at DOM 1 and preventDefault() is DOM 2 +.

Comment: Then delete the line or wrap it in an `if` block. No reason supporting older browsers should preclude you from readability and composability.

Comment: The addEventListener() is also DOM 2+.

Comment: @Rick Why DOM 1? Which browser do you need to support?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this...

```
function validateForm (itm) {
    var flag = true;
    flag = (validateUsername(itm.username, 'msgUsername') && flag);
    flag = (validatePassword(itm.password, 'msgPassword') && flag);

return flag;
}
```

Comment: I had to fix it up cause of syntax error: `return (validateUsername(itm.username, "msgUsername") && validateUsername(itm.passwordword, "msgPassword"));` It is working, but only executes the first validate function, not both in this case.

Comment: I edited my post, now it will execute both of the validations